# Sql error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error from below query

why is error occurred although the number of columns are equal.

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Line 46 is   `INSERT INTO #tmp_statement`

**Query**

```
DECLARE @PurchaseInvoiceID int,
        @PurchaseInvoiceNo varchar(max),
        @PurchaseInvoiceDate date,
        @Debit numeric(9, 2),
        @Balance numeric(9, 2)
SET @Balance = 0;
CREATE TABLE #tmp_statement (
  PurchaseInvoiceID int,
  PurchaseInvoiceNo  varchar(max),
  PurchaseInvoiceDate date
)
DECLARE rt_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID,
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo,
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate,
  CONVERT(decimal(9, 2), SUM(RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity * RequisitionDetails.UnitPrice)) AS Debit
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.Requisitions
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants
  ON dbo.Requisitions.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
INNER JOIN dbo.Suppliers
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.SupplierID = dbo.Suppliers.SupplierID
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories
  ON dbo.Requisitions.CategoryID = dbo.Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN dbo.PurchaseInvoices
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID = dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails
  ON dbo.RequisitionDetails.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountingDocuments
  ON dbo.PurchaseInvoices.DocumentID = dbo.AccountingDocuments.DocumentID
INNER JOIN dbo.Statement
  ON dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID = dbo.Statement.PurchaseInvoiceID
WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID = 1
AND dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-08-1' AND '2016-08-31'
GROUP BY dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID
OPEN rt_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate, @Debit
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @Balance = @Balance + @Debit 
  INSERT INTO #tmp_statement
    VALUES (@PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate, @Debit,@Balance)
  FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate, @Debit
END
CLOSE rt_cursor
DEALLOCATE rt_cursor
SELECT
  *
FROM #tmp_statement
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am getting this error from below query.why is error occurred although the number of columns are equal.

They are not equal..

your table..

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_statement (
  PurchaseInvoiceID int,
  PurchaseInvoiceNo  varchar(max),
  PurchaseInvoiceDate date
)
```

Your insert..

```
 INSERT INTO #tmp_statement
    VALUES (@PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate, @Debit,@Balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the table with the following columns:

- PurchaseInvoiceID int
- PurchaseInvoiceNo  varchar(max),
- PurchaseInvoiceDate date

You are then trying to specify too many columns in the `INSERT`.

```
VALUES (@PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate, @Debit,@Balance)
```

The column definitions need to match, therefore you can remove `@Debit` and `@Balance` as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_statement
VALUES (@PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate)
```

Or alternatively add a Debit and Balance column definition to the `#tmp_statement` table.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create columns for @Debit and @Balance if you want to insert values into them.

Answer (score 1):

your temp table #tmp_statement is declared with 3 column.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_statement (
  PurchaseInvoiceID int,
  PurchaseInvoiceNo  varchar(max),
  PurchaseInvoiceDate date
)
```

And you insert statement has 5 columns.

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_statement
VALUES (@PurchaseInvoiceID, @PurchaseInvoiceNo, @PurchaseInvoiceDate, @Debit,@Balance)
```

So the error is correct.
To fix it you need to either remove @Debit and @Balance from your insert statement, or add these columns to your create table statement.